# How to use such as?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, commas

I wonder if I have correctly used the phrase "such as" in the following sentence?

> The abrupt changes in weather patterns such as prolonged heatwaves
> and days of heavy rain are the onset symptoms of climate change.

Is it correct? Do I need to put it between commas like this?

> The abrupt changes in weather patterns, **such as prolonged heatwaves
> and days of heavy rain**, are the onset symptoms of climate change.

Comment: I was taught and its debated,  especially on this site, that if you need to pause when you are speaking what you have written then there should be a comma at that point.  However yours reads find. **the abrupt changes in weather patterns, prolonged heatwaves, days of heavy rain, are the signs of climate change**

Answer (score 1):

The abrupt changes in weather patterns such as prolonged heatwaves and days of heavy rain are the onset symptoms of climate change.

seems fine to me except for; "the onset symptoms".

I believe it should be; "the onset of the symptoms".

> *The abrupt changes in weather patterns such as prolonged heatwaves and days of heavy rain are the onset of the symptoms of climate change*.